# Having an entity registration for an organic group

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I have a website where we organise yearly events of 2 - 3 different types. To register users to the event, I'm currently using the entity registration module. (Tell me if you think this is not a good choice) I think I also want an organic group for every event, since every event should have it's own private forum, its own organisation wiki and image gallery. (If you think I don't need a separate organic group for that, see below, I'd appreciate your alternative suggestion!) For that reason, I created a new content type called "Event" which is a group type and has a registration field.

Some users might be really stupid, so I want the event registration to automatically trigger a group membership request, otherwise people will end up complaining "I registered for the event but I still can't access the event forum". How can I do that? (Maybe with rules? If yes, how?)

If you're thinking "Oh no, you're doing it all wrong!", I'd be happy to hear suggestions! Maybe there is a really clever way of doing it without having to resort to organic groups. The feature wishlist is: An event overview page, an event forum visible for all participants and staff, a staff forum visible only for staff (which will have a separate registration form), a staff wiki, an overview over the personal schedule and an image gallery for the event.

Comment: Not only do I think you are on the right track, but I think you might find [Subgroups](http://drupal.org/project/og_subgroups) handy.

Comment: Thanks :) Gives me some hope. I thought that subgroups are nice, but what could they help with my specific problem?

Comment: Public (private to event) forum vs private (staff) forum for instance.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. However, I'll still have to solve the registration issue.